# How to Desktop View, Tablet View ,Mobile view change inside a browser ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, media-queries, breakpoints

I am new to  Reactjs . How to add 3 views inside a browser,by automatically change view. 
[Reference Page Link](https://preview.colorlib.com/#meetme)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap all your content with a div and control the width of that div.

```
// App.js
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    const [state, setState] = useState('desktop');

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <button onClick={() => setState('desktop')}>Desktop</button>
            <button onClick={() => setState('tablet')}>Tablet</button>
            <button onClick={() => setState('phone')}>Phone</button>
            <div className={`container ${state}`}>Your content here</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

```
/*App.css*/
.App {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #766dff 0%, #88f3ff 100%);
}

/* General styling */
button {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
}

.container {
    /* General styling */
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    transition: all 1s;

    /* Center the container */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.desktop {
    width: 90%;
}

.tablet {
    width: 768px;
}

.phone {
    width: 480px;
}
```

```
/* index.css */
/* To make full width and height */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
#root {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct. You can simply give a width to the main container to 100% and place your other container with other elements inside of it, also specify width using @mediaqueries(" https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp "). This way, you can control the elements inside the main container. I can say for sure that you need to try it by yourself and see how everything works, use devtools(there is toogle device toolbar).