# How to display moblie view content inside a full-web- screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Reference Page Link:- https://preview.colorlib.com/#meetme
[image]

This question is already asked by a developer, but that solution does not work for me.
link of that question:- [How to Desktop View, Tablet View ,Mobile view change inside a browser ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68984124/how-to-desktop-view-tablet-view-mobile-view-change-inside-a-browser-reactjs)

Any help appreciated!. Thank You...

Answer (score 1):

well you can use inspect tool to view this

**rightClick** on the browser and select **inspect**.and select **toggle device toolbar** at top left of the pop up. you would get a **dimensions** at top of the web sreen you can take any screens from it .

or you can simply resize the browser to check it :D
[image]